# fat32 partition overwritten by Mint image

Tags: linux-mint, data-recovery, ext4, fat32

1. Was Running Mint 17.1
2. Two Kingston USB devices attached
3. accidentally written a Mint image the the archive Kingston by the image writer, and lost my fat32 partition with important data collection.
4. Tried 'Testdisk' only to search the device for fat32, with no success

Is there any way to get that back?

Comment: Short answer - no

Answer (score 2):

The previous file system structure is likely lost. Without a professional lab, you may be able to scrape some of the data off there with [PhotoRec](//help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery) (link to Ubuntu Wiki, since you seem to be asking about Linux Mint).

Otherwise, data recovery labs can sometimes read previously used flash cells, that have been deallocated by the wear levelling algorithm of the drive and are not yet overwritten by new data. Though, this is a finicky process and requires knowledge of the flash cell controller either through cooperation by the manufacturer (more likely for large companies like Kingston) or reverse-engineering and may not come cheap.